# Can I run python code on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, python, development, ipados

I usually use an iPad to answer questions or program. Before answering, I wish to test to ensure they function well.

At this situation, I find it sometimes inconvenient to get to a computer.

How can I test python scripts on iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not start with a nice pair of programs:

- [Pythonista](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097?mt=8) for a very nice self contained app that runs python
- [Prompt](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt-2/id917437289?mt=8) to ssh into Unix / macOS computers if you need more custom code or libraries to run
- [GitHub Codespaces](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/setting-up-your-python-project-for-codespaces) has good Python support and nice thorough documentation.

Comment: There's also GitHub Codespaces.

Comment: I've added that with an edit @ma1234 Thank you - if you have any iPad tips, please edit them in as well. My iPad is in the shop so I can't test it right now properly.